# Android 23 API IllegalArgumentException error

Tags: java, android

I am get this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null` ,

From the next line - `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 50, (LocationListener) this);` I compile the project with the 23 API. but when I try the 21 API there is no problem. can anyone help me understand why this is happened and how can I fix that.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

```
    // ///Criteria //////////

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    }else{
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);
    }
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 50, (LocationListener) this); // (in miliseconds) // (in meters) update location
```

Comment: `bestProvider` is null. Add the code where you set this variable.

Comment: Ok but I set my bestProvider like this -   String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true); 

so why the bestProvider is null and how can I fix it ?.

Comment: You need to request one of `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions at runtime starting with Android 6 (API 23).

Comment: Post what are your `criteria`.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I add the criteria to the post

Comment: **a)** `setAccuracy()` only takes `ACCURACY_FINE` or `ACCURACY_COARSE`. Read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#setAccuracy(int)). **b)** That if check is unnecessary because `static final int`s are compiled to values. Furthermore don't bother supporting older devices than Gingerbread anyway. **c)** You want a high precision provider which is GPS but you also want low power consumption which is the opposite of GPS. Meaning no provider will match your criteria resulting in `null`.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thank you ! So I need to take only one of ACCURACY_FINE or ACCURACY_COARSE and this is need to fix the problem of the precision provider and the low power consumption ?

Answer (score 0):

**LocationManager api 24 calls:**

```
public void requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, 
                                   float minDistance, LocationListener listener) 
public void requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, 
                                   float minDistance, LocationListener listener, 
                                   Looper looper) 
public void requestLocationUpdates(long minTime, float minDistance, 
                                   Criteria criteria, LocationListener listener, 
                                   Looper looper)
public void requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, 
                                   float minDistance, PendingIntent intent) 
public void requestLocationUpdates(long minTime, float minDistance, 
                                   Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent)
```

> throws IllegalArgumentException if **provider is null or doesn't exist on this device** OR if **listener is null**

**how handle ???** 
example1:

```
    try {
        LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(args...);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
           // handle exception here 
        }
    }
```

example2:

```
    String provider = (LocationManager.getBestProvider(args...);
    boolean allow = provider != null && listener != null
    if(allow) LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(args...);
    else // scream yell log etc...
```

sources:

```
/**
 * Returns the name of the provider that best meets the given criteria. Only providers
 * that are permitted to be accessed by the calling activity will be
 * returned.  If several providers meet the criteria, the one with the best
 * accuracy is returned.  If no provider meets the criteria,
 * the criteria are loosened in the following sequence:
 *
 * <ul>
 * <li> power requirement
 * <li> accuracy
 * <li> bearing
 * <li> speed
 * <li> altitude
 * </ul>
 *
 * <p> Note that the requirement on monetary cost is not removed
 * in this process.
 *
 * @param criteria the criteria that need to be matched
 * @param enabledOnly if true then only a provider that is currently enabled is returned
 * @return name of the provider that best matches the requirements
 */
public String getBestProvider(Criteria criteria, boolean enabledOnly) 

/**
 * Register for location updates using the named provider, and a
 * pending intent.
 *
 * <p>See {@link #requestLocationUpdates(long, float, Criteria, PendingIntent)}
 * for more detail on how to use this method.
 *
 * @param provider the name of the provider with which to register
 * @param minTime minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds
 * @param minDistance minimum distance between location updates, in meters
 * @param listener a {@link LocationListener} whose
 * {@link LocationListener#onLocationChanged} method will be called for
 * each location update
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if provider is null or doesn't exist
 * on this device
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if listener is null
 * @throws RuntimeException if the calling thread has no Looper
 * @throws SecurityException if no suitable permission is present
 */
@RequiresPermission(anyOf = {ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION})
public void requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance,
        LocationListener listener)
```